# WCF timeout and not responding to request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

WCF timeout issue

I have a really simple WCF with BasicHTTPBinding
It returns an XMLElement which is a dataset transformed.  The data returned only contains about 1500 rows with 13 columns wide.
The setup of the WCF is on a dedicated server hosted in IIS 7.5 on a windows 2008 machine.
The setup of the client is a dedicated webserver hosted in IIS 7.5 on a windows 2008 machine.

The website calling the WCF service is on a different machine which is part of the workgroup but not on the domain. (It is based in a different location, with a secure VPN tunnel)
I have exhausted all options with the bindings settings and timeout limits on both server and client.

I have tried:

- Increasing the maxReceivedMessageSize on client and server
- Increased the maxItemsInObjectGraph on client and server
- Used the WCF tracing on both server and client and nothing shows as faulting
- Increased the timeouts on both client and server.
- The WCFmachine can be seen from the webserver machine using ping. I have also tried using the IP address instead of the name so it doesn’t need to do a DNS lookup.

The problem is that the data does not get returned to the client all the time. Sometimes it can work instantaneously and other times it will return the data after a short period of time but the majority of the time it will return an error message like this:

System.Exception: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

Or like this:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**NOTE**: Biggest thing to note is that this DOES work 100% of the time from a webserver which is located on the same domain as the WCF machine.

Here is the full set up I am using:

Client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderListSvc" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SerializerObjectGraph">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://WCFmachine/AxceWCF.OrderListSvc.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderListSvc" contract="OrderListSVC.IOrderListSvc" name="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderListSvc" behaviorConfiguration="SerializerObjectGraph" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Server config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="AxceWCF.OrderListSvc" behaviorConfiguration="SerializerTest">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AxceWCF.IOrderListSvc" behaviorConfiguration="SerializerObjectGraph" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderListSvc">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://WCFmachine/AxceWCF.OrderListSvc.svc" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SerializerTest">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SerializerObjectGraph">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderListSvc" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>  
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

WCF Service:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IOrderListSvc

<OperationContract()>
Function LoadOrderList(ByVal UserID As Integer) As XmlElement

End Interface
```

WCF cont ...

```
Public Function LoadOrderList(UserID As Integer) As Xml.XmlElement Implements IOrderListSvc.LoadOrderList

  Dim doc As New XmlDocument
  doc = OrderListDetails.LoadOrderList(UserID)

  Return doc.DocumentElement
End Function
```

Actual Function to return Data

```
Public Function LoadOrderList(ByVal UserID As Integer) As XmlDocument

        Using cConn As Connection = CreateDBConnection()
            cConn.Open()

            Dim strSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

            strSQL.Append("SELECT O.Orderno, O.OrderDate, O.Quantity, o.assetTypeClassID, o.PartyID, o.AssetTypeID, o.PartNumber, o.item, o.Stock, o.SPExcl, o.Maker, o.AssetTypeClassName, o.Obsolete ")
            strSQL.Append("FROM Orders o ")
            strSQL.Append("WHERE O.OrderDate > dateadd(YEAR, -5, getDate() AND (o.UserID = '" & UserID & "') ")

            strSQL.Append("ORDER BY O.OrderDate ")

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim dt As DataTable = cConn.ExecuteTable(strSQL.ToString)

            dt.TableName = "OrderList"
            ds.Merge(dt)

            Dim dsXML As New XmlDocument
            dsXML.LoadXml(ds.GetXml)

            Return dsXML

       End using

End Function
```

Call to return results from WCF:

```
Public Function TestOrderList(ByVal UserID As Integer) As DataTable

    Dim wsResults As XmlElement = Nothing
    Dim client As OrderListSVC.OrderListSvcClient = Nothing

    Try

        client = New OrderListSVC.OrderListSvcClient

        wsResults = client.LoadOrderList(UserID)

        DirectCast(client, ICommunicationObject).Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)

    Finally

        If client IsNot Nothing Then
            DirectCast(client, ICommunicationObject).Abort()
        End If

        Return Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```